# Mobile App - Can I change hybrid app to native app?

Tags: android, ios, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to make a hybrid mobile application. As you know, hybrid apps would be slow if user traffic bigger. This is would be useless concern, If I launch hybrid mobile app, If users are bigger, can I change it to native app later through "update" way?

The update way is, without re-registration in app market(appstore, google play etc), keeping downloads count and many reviews on it.

Comment: "As you know, hybrid apps would be slow if user traffic bigger" -- well-written hybrid apps do not use any more bandwidth than do their native equivalents.

Comment: @CommonsWare I red docs in somewhere that hybrid has disadvantage on speed. maybe more than 3 years ago, oh. so you mean it's not related with platform. that's interesting.

Comment: "hybrid has disadvantage on speed" -- speed != bandwidth.